# Writing well-founded programs in Coq using Fix or Program Fixpoint

Tags: coq

Following the example given in the chapter [GeneralRec](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.GeneralRec.html) of Chlipala book, I'm trying to write the mergesort algorithm.

Here is my code

```
Require Import Nat.

Fixpoint insert (x:nat) (l: list nat) : list nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => x::nil
  | y::l' => if leb x y then
              x::l
            else
              y::(insert x l')
  end.

Fixpoint merge (l1 l2 : list nat) : list nat :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => l2
  | x::l1' => insert x (merge l1' l2)
  end.

Fixpoint split (l : list nat) : list nat * list nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => (nil,nil)
  | x::nil => (x::nil,nil)
  | x::y::l' =>
    let (ll,lr) := split l' in
    (x::ll,y::lr)
  end.

Definition lengthOrder (l1 l2 : list nat) :=
  length l1 < length l2.

Theorem lengthOrder_wf : well_founded lengthOrder.
Admitted.
```

The problem is that it is not possible to write the mergeSort function with the command `Fixpoint` since the function is not structurally decreasing :

```
Fixpoint mergeSort (l: list nat) : list nat :=
  if leb (length l) 1 then l
  else
    let (ll,lr) := split l in
    merge (mergeSort ll) (mergeSort lr).
```

Instead, one can use the command `Program Fixpoint` or `Definition` with the term `Fix` (as in Chlipala book).

However, if I'm writing this

```
Definition mergeSort : list nat -> list nat.
refine (Fix lengthOrder_wf (fun (l: list nat) => list nat)
      (fun (l : list nat) => (fun mergeSort : (forall ls : list nat, lengthOrder ls l -> list nat )=>
                           if leb (length l) 1 then
                             let (ll,lr) := split l in
                             merge (mergeSort ll _) (mergeSort lr _)
                           else
                             l))).
```

I'm getting impossible goals :

```
2 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID 65)

  l : list nat
  mergeSort : forall ls : list nat, lengthOrder ls l -> list nat
  ll, lr : list nat
  ============================
  lengthOrder ll l

subgoal 2 (ID 66) is:
 lengthOrder lr l
```

That is why Chlipala suggests to change the definition of mergeSort this way:

```
Definition mergeSort : list nat -> list nat.
  refine (Fix lengthOrder_wf (fun _ => list nat)
              (fun (ls : list nat)
                 (mergeSort : forall ls' : list nat, lengthOrder ls' ls -> list nat) =>
                 if Compare_dec.le_lt_dec 2 (length ls)
                 then let lss := split ls in
                      merge (mergeSort (fst lss) _) (mergeSort (snd lss) _)
                 else ls)).
```

that generates the following goals:

```
2 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID 68)

  ls : list nat
  mergeSort : forall ls' : list nat, lengthOrder ls' ls -> list nat
  l : 2 <= length ls
  lss := split ls : list nat * list nat
  ============================
  lengthOrder (fst lss) ls

subgoal 2 (ID 69) is:
 lengthOrder (snd lss) ls
```

This new definition sounds like magic to me. So I wonder:

- Fom the first definition, is it still possible to proof the well-foudness of the function?
- Otherwise why the first definition cannot work?
- How a basic user can go from the first definition to the second easily?

Comment: `length (fst (split l)) < length l` is provable! Observe that you have `H : 2 <= length l` in the context. The `split_wf1` lemma in CPDT's chapter you linked is very helpful here: `Lemma split_wf1 : forall ls, 2 <= length ls -> lengthOrder (fst (split ls)) ls`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to see that you need to make two changes in order to get to A. Chlipala's solution.

1) When doing `split` you somehow need to remember that `ll` and `lr` came from split, otherwise they would be some arbitrary lists, which cannot possibly be shorter than the original list `l`.

The following piece of code fails to save that kind of information:

```
let (ll,lr) := split l in
  merge (mergeSort ll _) (mergeSort lr _)
```

and, thus, needs to be replaced with

```
let lss := split ls in
  merge (mergeSort (fst lss) _) (mergeSort (snd lss) _)
```

which keeps what we need.

The failure happens due to Coq's inability to remember that `ll` and `lr` come from `split l` and that happens because `let (ll,lr)` is just `match` in disguise (see the manual, [§2.2.3](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#sect69)).

Recall that the aims of pattern-matching is to (loosely speaking)

- unpack the components of some value of an inductive datatype and *bind* them to some names (we'll need this in the 2nd part of my answer) and
- replace the original definition with its special cases in the corresponding pattern-match branches.

Now, observe that `split l` *does not* occur anywhere in the goal or context before we pattern-match on it. We just arbitrarily introduce it into the definition. That's why pattern-matching doesn't give us anything -- we can't replace `split l` with its "special case" (`(ll,lr)`) in the goal or context, because there is no `split l` anywhere.

There is an alternative way of doing this by using logical equality (`=`):

```
(let (ll, lr) as s return (s = split l -> list nat) := split l in
   fun split_eq => merge (mergeSort ll _) (mergeSort lr _)) eq_refl
```

This is analogous to using the `remember` tactic. We've got rid of `fst` and `snd`, but it is a huge overkill and I wouldn't recommend it.

---

2) Another thing we need to prove is the fact that `ll` and `lr` are shorter than `l` when `2 <= length l`.

Since an `if`-expression is a `match` in disguise as well (it works for any inductive datatype with *exactly* two constructors), we need some mechanism to remember that `leb 2 (length l) = true` in the `then` branch. Again, since we don't have `leb` anywhere, this information gets lost.

There are at least two possible solutions to the problem:

- either we remember `leb 2 (length l)` as an equation (just as we did in the 1st part), or
- we can use some comparison function with result type behaving like `bool` (so it can represent two alternatives), but it should also remember some additional information we need. Then we could pattern-match on the comparison result and extract the information, which, of course, in this case have to be a proof of `2 <= length l`.

What we need is a type which is able to carry a proof of `m <= n` in the case when `leb m n` returns `true` and a proof of, say, `m > n` otherwise.
There is a type in the standard library that does exactly that! It's called [`sumbool`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Specif.html#sumbool):

```
Inductive sumbool (A B : Prop) : Set :=
    left : A -> {A} + {B} | right : B -> {A} + {B}
```

`{A} + {B}` is just a notation (syntactic sugar) for `sumbool A B`.
Just as `bool`, it has two constructors, but in addition it remembers a proof of either of two propositions `A` and `B`. Its advantage over `bool` shows up when you do case analysis on it with `if`: you get a proof of `A` in the `then` branch and a proof of `B` in the `else` branch. In other words, you get to use context you saved beforehand, whereas `bool` doesn't carry any context (only in the mind of the programmer).

And we need exactly that! Well, not in the `else` branch, but we would like to get `2 <= length l` in our `then` branch. So, let us ask Coq if it already has a comparison function with the return type like that:

```
Search (_ -> _ -> {_ <= _} + {_}).

(*
output:
le_lt_dec: forall n m : nat, {n <= m} + {m < n}
le_le_S_dec: forall n m : nat, {n <= m} + {S m <= n}
le_ge_dec: forall n m : nat, {n <= m} + {n >= m}
le_gt_dec: forall n m : nat, {n <= m} + {n > m}
le_dec: forall n m : nat, {n <= m} + {~ n <= m}
*)
```

*Any* of the five results would do, because we need a proof only in one case.

Hence, we can replace `if leb 2 (length l) then ...` with `if le_lt_dec 2 (length l) ...` and get `2 <= length` in the proof context, which will let us finish the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point is that all the hypotheses that Coq needs should be reflected in the types of the expressions and hence, we need dependend lemmas/constructions to achieve that. In the end, this is straightforward!

Comment: Yes. Often we have to be more explicit about the information flow compared   to ordinary functional programming.