# Coq losing information from if-statement when doing recursive function with Program

Tags: coq

I want to write this recursive variant of `gcd` as simply and "naturally" as possible in Coq.

```
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Program.

Program Fixpoint gcd (a b:nat) {measure b} :=
  if 0 <? b then gcd b (a mod b) else a.
Next Obligation.
  (* Here I need to prove that `a mod b < b` *)
  apply Nat.mod_upper_bound.
```

Now I need to prove that `b <> 0` but I have lost the info that we are in the `0 <? b = false` branch.

```
  a, b : nat
  gcd : nat -> forall b0 : nat, b0 < b -> nat
  ============================
  b <> 0
```

How do I keep the information from the if statement?

I know I could use `match`, but how to I write it with `if`?)

```
Program Fixpoint gcd (a b:nat) {measure b} :=
  match b with 0 => a | S b' => gcd b (a mod b) end.
Next Obligation.
  apply Nat.mod_upper_bound.
  (* Goal:  S b' <> 0 *)
  congruence.
Defined.
```

=== EDIT ===

I noticed that Coq (in more recent versions?) remembers the association between `0 <? b` and the match patterns (`true` or `false` in this case).  Or is it a feature of `Program`? Anyway, I thought that `if` essentially was expanded into this `match` statement, but apparently it isn't...

```
Program Fixpoint gcd (a b:nat) {measure b} : nat:=
  match 0<?b with
  | true => gcd b (a mod b)
  | false => a
  end.
Next Obligation.
  apply Nat.mod_upper_bound.
  (* now we have ` true = (0 <? b)` in the assumptions, and the goal `b <> 0` *)
  now destruct b.
Defined.
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285235/writing-well-founded-programs-in-coq-using-fix-or-program-fixpoint) is a related question.

Comment: Thanks! It explains well _how to think_ about this.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting observation! Yes, you are right, it is a feature of `Program`. I updated my answer with a couple quotes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use `lt_dec` to do that.

```
lt_dec
     : forall n m : nat, {n < m} + {~ n < m}
```

This way we can keep the proofs we need in the context, unlike when using `<?`, which returns a `bool`.

```
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Program.

Program Fixpoint gcd (a b:nat) {measure b} :=
  if lt_dec 0 b then gcd b (a mod b) else a.
Next Obligation.
  apply Nat.mod_upper_bound.
  now destruct H.
Defined.
```

---

Yes, it is a feature of `Program`. Actually the reference manual explain it in a very clear manner (see [§24.1](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual027.html#sec752)):

> Generation of equalities. A `match` expression is always generalized by the corresponding equality. As an example, the expression:
>
> ```
> match x with
>   | 0 => t
>   | S n => u
>   end.
> ```
>
> will be first rewritten to:
>
> ```
> (match x as y return (x = y -> _) with
> | 0 => fun H : x = 0 -> t
> | S n => fun H : x = S n -> u
> end) (eq_refl n).
> ```

Here is the reason why `if` is different:

> To give more control over the generation of equalities, the typechecker will fall back directly to Coq’s usual typing of dependent pattern-matching if a `return` or `in` clause is specified. Likewise, the `if` construct is not treated specially by `Program` so boolean tests in the code are not automatically reflected in the obligations. One can use the `dec` combinator to get the correct hypotheses as in:
>
> ```
> Coq < Program Definition id (n : nat) : { x : nat | x = n } :=
>         if dec (leb n 0) then 0
>         else S (pred n).
> ```