# Finding a well founded relation to prove termination of a function that stops decreasing at some point

Tags: coq, termination, totality

Suppose we have:

```
Require Import ZArith Program.

Program Fixpoint range (from to : Z) {measure f R} : list  :=
  if from <? to
  then from :: range (from + 1) to
  else [].
```

I'd like to convince Coq that this terminates - I tried by measuring the size of the range as `abs (to - from)`. However, this doesn't quite work because once the range is empty (that is, `from >= to`), it simply starts increasing once again.

I've also tried measuring with:

```
Definition get_range (from to : Z) : option nat :=
  let range := (to - from) in 
    if (range <? 0)
    then None
    else Some (Z_to_nat (Z.abs range) (Z.abs_nonneg range)).
```

using my custom:

```
Definition preceeds_eq (l r : option nat) : Prop :=
  match l, r with
    | None, None         => False
    | None, (Some _)     => True
    | (Some _), None     => False
    | (Some x), (Some y) => x < y
  end.
```

and the cast:

```
Definition Z_to_nat (z : Z) (p : 0 <= z) : nat.
Proof.
  dependent destruction z.
    - exact (0%nat).
    - exact (Pos.to_nat p).
    - assert (Z.neg p < 0) by apply Zlt_neg_0.
      contradiction.
Defined.
```

But it runs into the issue that I cannot show that `None < None` and using reflexive `preceeds_eq` makes the relation not well founded, which brings me back to the same problem.

Is there a way to convince Coq that `range` terminates? Is my approach completely broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you map the length of you interval to `nat` using `Z.abs_nat` or `Z.to_nat` functions, and use a function deciding if the range is not-empty with a more informative result type (`Z_lt_dec`) then the solution becomes very simple:

```
Require Import ZArith Program.

Program Fixpoint range (from to : Z) {measure (Z.abs_nat (to - from))} : list Z :=
  if Z_lt_dec from to
  then from :: range (from + 1) to
  else [].
Next Obligation. apply Zabs_nat_lt; auto with zarith. Qed.
```

Using `Z_lt_dec` instead of its boolean counter-part gives you the benefit of propagating the proof of `from < to` into the context, which gives you the ability to deal with the proof obligation easily.

Comment: I had like 60 tactic proof of `range from to < range (from + 1) to` only to then realize I can't have a reflexive well founded relation... and all of this nonsense can be replaced with a single line... thank you Anton, now if you'll excuse me, I need to uninstall Coq :).

Comment: Also how on Earth is a computational decision procedure (the bool one) somehow less expressive than just a statement about decidability :(.

Comment: `Z_lt_dec` is a decision procedure too, but in addition to marking the result as true or false (which are called `left` and `right` respectively) it also attaches a proof to the result. It's quite suggestively called `sumbool` -- once I tried to explain its usage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42313822/2747511)(in its second half).